# Godot speed up mobile HTML5 Export GLES2 load time

Tags: html5, opengl-es2, godot

I got a small Godot project that should be played on mobile devices, however the load time of a GLES2/ HTML5 export project of Godot takes 20+ seconds to load from the server.

To decrease the load time I already tried to decrease the pack size (500kb), but this didn't make a difference. From the project and export settings I couldn't find any option that would decrease the load time either.

Are there other ways to decrease the load time of a Godot GLES2/ HTML5 project?

I can't share the project itself but if I need to display certain settings or need to add more information to make the problem clearer please let me know. =)

Comment: Have you though of including more assets to the basic project, when the user downloads it from a Store ?

Comment: @TomTsagk this isn't a project that is downloaded from a store but instead loaded from a website/ server. I'll edit my question to make it more clear. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: Is the load time after downloading the assets from the server? Or is the bottleneck in the download time of the assets from the server?